# How to extract image name from string using python regexp?

Tags: python, regex

Having a text like this:

```
body = """Some junk texts here.
<img src="/images/15244/somerandomname.jpg" class="news-img">
More texts here"""
```

I'm wondering how can I extract `somerandomname.jpg` using python regexp?

What I came up with is this:

```
import re
regex = re.findall('/images/(\d+)/(\w+).jpg', body)
```

But it does return an empty list.

Comment: I tried your exact code and I got this `[('15244', 'somerandomname')]`
Try to add `r` before your expression and capture the .jpg too: `regex = re.findall(r'/images/(\d+)/(\w+\.jpg)', body)`.

Comment: Same here. I got a list with a tuple with what you wanted (except for `somerandomname` instead of `somerandomname.jpg`).

EDIT: @Babr can you show you how you execute your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall` returns either the entire matches if no capturing groups (`(...)`) defined in the pattern, or captured groups if these defined. Since you've got capturing groups, the latter takes place.

Remove capturing groups to get the entire match:

```
regex = re.findall('/images/\d+/\w+.jpg', body)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/n1f9R8

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
regex = re.findall('/images/(\d+)/([^"]+)', body)
image_src = regex[0][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## you just need to group only image name part.

check this expression it will also work for all other extension i.e.  [jpg,png,ttf etc...](https://regex101.com/r/cVey1o/1/)

> re.findall('/images/\d+/(\w+.\w{3,4})', body)
>   output: ['somerandomname.jpg']

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, and since you just want to capture the name this will work.

```
import re
body = """Some junk texts here.
<img src="/images/15244/somerandomname.jpg" class="news-img">
More texts here"""
regex = re.findall(r'/images/\d+/(\w+.jpg)', body)
print regex
```